# Why is initial_word = input("Please type the word again: ") not being called?

Tags: python

My code is not working. Ok, first I type any word, say: "MARCUS".  Then the user asks "Would you like to delete some vowels?". And I input "Yes".  It's supposed to ask me: "Please type the word again", but it doesn't.  Pycharm (my application of choice) does not say I have any issues, but something is wrong here.

Relevant code:

```
while [True]:
            original = input("Type any word in the English language.  Make sure it is not over 10 characters.  If you would like to exit this application, type 'Exit'.").upper()
            if len(original.upper()) <= 8 and original.upper().isalpha():
                keepOrDeleteVowel1 = input("Would you like to delete some vowels?  Type 'yes' to choose which vowels you would like to delete, or 'no' to type a new word.")
                if keepOrDeleteVowel1 == "no" or "No" or "NO":
                    original=original.replace("A", "4")
                    original=original.replace("E", "3")
                    original=original.replace("I", "1")
                    original=original.replace("L", "7")
                    original=original.replace("B", "8")
                    original=original.replace("G", "9")
                    original=original.replace("S", "5")
                    original=original.replace(" ", "")
                    print("This is your word: " + original +  "." + " Enjoy your new license plate! Thank you for using this app.")
                    break
                elif keepOrDeleteVowel1 == "yes" or "Yes" or "YES":
                    initial_word = input("Please type the word again: ")
                    vowel = input("Type the vowels you want to remove.  Tip: If your word begins or ends with a vowel, try not to delete the vowel because the word might not be recognizable.")
                    if type(vowel) is str:
                        if len(vowel) <=5 and vowel == [0-24]:
                            initial_word = initial_word.replace(vowel.lower(), '')
                            initial_word = initial_word.replace(vowel.upper(), '')
                        else:
                            print('Wrong input.')
                    print("This is your word: " + initial_word +  "." + " Enjoy your new license plate! Thank you for using this app.")
                    break
```

Here is the output:

```
Type any word in the English language.Make sure it is not over 10 characters.  If you would like to exit this application, type 'Exit'.
MARCUS
Would you like to delete some vowels?  Type 'yes' to choose which vowels you would like to delete, or 'no' to type a new word.
Yes
This is your word: M4RCU5. Enjoy your new license plate! Thank you for using this app.
```

(HERE IT'S SUPPOSED TO SAY: PLEASE TYPE THE WORD AGAIN)

Thanks in advance for the help, much appreciated.

Comment: Side note -> `while [True]` should be `while True`.

Comment: `keepOrDeleteVowel1 == "no" or "No" or "NO":` is not how you check against multiple things. You need to compare `keepOrDeleteVowel1` individually to each variable, or do something like put it in a set and test for membership.

Comment: BTW, `if type(vowel) is str:` is nonsense. Assuming you use Python 3 `vowel` will always be a string because it is the return value of the `input` function.